# Xamarin Forms Syncfusion DataGrid Swipe not working properly

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion datagrid to show data. When I use swipe feature in it to delete a row then row is deleted but delete option still remains there without any row and after that if I add a new row then deleted row remains blank and new row appears after blank row.

My code is:

```
lstSelectedBookATestViewModel.RemoveAt(swipeRowIndex-1);
dataGrid_Services.ItemsSource = lstSelectedBookATestViewModel;
dataGrid_Services.View.Refresh();
```

Please help.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP2sh.jpg)

Comment: Please provide code on how you delete the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset swipe of DataGrid and no need to rebind data with grid.

```
 lstSelectedBookATestViewModel.RemoveAt(swipeRowIndex - 1);
 dataGrid_Services.ResetSwipeOffset();
 dataGrid_Services.View.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

We have checked your query and prepared the sample using your code snippet for Swiping delete and tested with Xamarin.Forms v2.4.0.280 and SfDataGrid v15.4.0.17, the swiping does not appear with blank row and new row added properly.

For your reference we have attached our working copy of the sample in the below location, please refer it.

Sample : http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/193097/ze/SfDataGridDemo-1765150173

In case, if you were still able to reproduce the issue, then could you please share your Xamarin.Forms and SfDataGrid version, and also please share your testing device details. Otherwise, please do revert us by modifying our sample to replicate the issue or share your sample along with clear replication procedure to proceed further.

Regards,
Harikrishnan